# Enter date and it will automaticly know which day it is

Tags: java, android

Just a quick question.
Is it possible with Android Studio to enter a date: "09/05/2017" and it will give a output to the user that it's Tuesday?

Comment: Google it please.

Comment: what you tried where is the code?

Comment: Have you tried searching? I get a lot of results with `"Java date to day name"`

Comment: Sorry. Yea I actualy tried to search on the web. But I guess I have searched the wrong sentence I guess. When I searched I got stuff like how to get output from the calendar widget. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks for sending me what to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code for that

```
        String dateString  = "09/05/2017";
        try {
            Date  date1  = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(dateString);
            String day  = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(date1);
            System.out.print(day);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: @kasper please accept the answer if it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this code`:

```
try {
            String input = "09/05/2017";
            SimpleDateFormat inFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            Date date = inFormat.parse(input);
            SimpleDateFormat outFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            String goal = outFormat.format(date);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), goal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```